# Converting an Excel range into an array

Tags: vba, excel

I'm iterating through a list of possible values that reside in a named range on a worksheet. Since accessing ranges is slow, I wanted an easy way to convert them to an array and came up with the function below that does so. Is there a better way of setting my code up?

```
Public Function ConvertRangeIntoArray(ByVal convertRange As Range) As String()
    Dim temporaryVariant As Variant
    Dim is2DArray As Boolean
    Select Case True
        Case convertRange.Rows.Count = 1
            temporaryVariant = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(convertRange))
        Case convertRange.columns.Count = 1
            temporaryVariant = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(convertRange)
        Case Else
            temporaryVariant = convertRange
            is2DArray = True
    End Select

    Dim returnValue() As String
    Dim rw As Long
    Dim cl As Long
    If is2DArray Then
        ReDim returnValue(LBound(temporaryVariant) To UBound(temporaryVariant), LBound(temporaryVariant, 2) To UBound(temporaryVariant, 2))
        For rw = LBound(temporaryVariant) To UBound(temporaryVariant)
            For cl = LBound(temporaryVariant, 2) To UBound(temporaryVariant, 2)
                returnValue(rw, cl) = CStr(temporaryVariant(rw, cl))
            Next
        Next
    Else
        ReDim returnValue(LBound(temporaryVariant) To UBound(temporaryVariant))
        For cl = LBound(temporaryVariant) To UBound(temporaryVariant)
            returnValue(cl) = CStr(temporaryVariant(cl))
        Next
    End If

    ConvertRangeIntoArray = returnValue
End Function
```

Comment: What's the point of the double `WorksheetFunction.Transpose`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kudos for explicit `Public` and the `ByVal` parameter. I wouldn't make it return a `String()` array though.

You can't *know* that every value in the source `Range` *can* be converted to a `String`.

> ```
> returnValue(cl) = CStr(temporaryVariant(cl))
> ```

This instruction will make your function fail if the `convertRange` contains any `Error` value. You need to first verify whether `IsError(temporaryVariant(cl))` before you can attempt any safe type conversion.

But then, what would you do with a value that can't be converted? Remove it from the results? Return an empty string?

What if the range is all numeric values, that the calling code needs to add up; there's some serious overhead going on with iterating both dimensions of a 2D array to convert everything to a `String`, and then doing the same thing again to convert strings back to `Double` for proper calculations.

IMO that's one of the cases where you're better off just returning a `Variant`. That significantly cuts down the implementation:

```
Public Function ToArray(ByVal target As Range) As Variant
    Select Case True
        Case target.Rows.Count = 1
            'horizontal 1D range
            ToArray = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(target)).Value
        Case target.columns.Count = 1
            'vertical 1D range
            ToArray = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(target).Value
        Case Else
            '2D array: let Excel to the conversion itself
            ToArray = target.Value
    End Select
End Function
```

Note I renamed the function to a more straightforward `ToArray` which lets the argument speak for itself, and renamed `convertRange` to the more idiomatic (it comes up a lot in worksheet event handlers) `target` (it's also a *noun*, which is more appropriate than something that looks like a *verb* for naming a variable).

The caller now has access to the *actual* types - with everything it means: if a value's type `IsError`, then the caller needs to deal with it accordingly. If a value `IsNumeric`, then the caller can perform arithmetic operations on it without incurring implicit type conversions (aside from unwrapping the value from the `Variant`). If the value `IsDate`, then the caller can work with dates without ever having to deal with how VBA might be representing that date value in a `String`.

And performance-wise, it's now as fast as it's going to get (pretty much instant), regardless of the size of the returned array.

I'm not too fond of `Select Case True`. `Case` conditions are still going to be evaluated sequentially until one matches, so at the end of the day it's not much different from a more conventional construct:

```
Public Function ToArray(ByVal target As Range) As Variant
    If target.Rows.Count = 1 Then
        'horizontal 1D range
        ToArray = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(target.Value))
    ElseIf target.columns.Count = 1 Then
        'vertical 1D range
        ToArray = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(target.Value)
    Else
        '2D array: let Excel to the conversion itself
        ToArray = target.Value
    End If
End Function
```

...which removes an indentation level, and puts the conditions where we'd normally expect them. We're also explicitly assigning to the `.Value` of the range, transposed or not, instead of implicitly pulling the ranges' default member.

Comment: Originally it was set up as variant but second guessed myself, I changed it to string since all occurrences will only ever be text. Is there any benefit, aside from less typing of using a `Select Case` over `If ... Else if`?

Comment: I rarely use `Select Case` for anything other than dealing with enum values. I guess *it depends* ;-) ..as for the string conversions, if the caller is going to be iterating the array then it's best to let the caller do the string conversions; that way you only iterate it once.

Comment: Shouldn't we be doing `Toarray = target.value`? Since ToArray is returning a variant, it could return `target` as a range. This wouldn't be the desired effect (unless I am mistaken about the intent). To clarify, I know the default member of `Range` is `Value` but I prefer to rely on explicit assignments and not implicit. I am assuming that we can avoid ToArray becoming the Range by not using the `Set` keyword, but would using `.Value` not be a better approach anyways?

Comment: @BrandonBarney that is absolutely correct!

Comment: @Mat'sMug, you have a minor error in your code. It is `ElseIf` instead of `Else If`, right.

Comment: [Brandon](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/161779/converting-an-excel-range-into-an-array/161784#comment307133_161784) stated to use **`target.Value`**, but you changed your code to `[...].Transpose(target).Value`. Of course this raises an error, because there is no `Transpose.Value`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx

If you declare your array variable as

```
Dim temporaryVariant() As Variant
```

it will automatically pick up the cells as a 2-d array, without needing any funny business to avoid picking up the `Range` object.

That should make it a lot easier to make your `String()` later.

You should also cache the `LBound()` and `UBound()` results; it's faster (and less code)